# How can I serialize to BSON a class having a recursive definition?

Tags: c#, mongodb, visual-studio-2013, bson

I am facing trouble in trying to serialize this C# class to a BSON Document using the latest Csharp driver 1.9.1 for MongoDB :-

```
public class Node
{
    public string name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public List<Node> children
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int size
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public Node()
    {
        children = new List<Node>();
    }
}
```

I would like to know whether we can serialize this recursive class definition (I am trying to create a tree structure) using the AutoMap() facility or not. If not, what should I do to serialize this? Do I need to manually write the code for serializing the tree bottom-up?

I have this in my initialization code (for registering the class):

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Node>();
```

Also, how should I convert an instance of Node to a BSON Document as when I try to use :

```
var bsonDoc = node1.ToBson();
```

It gives an error saying:

> Error 1   'Node' does not contain a definition for 'ToBson' and no extension method 'ToBson' accepting a first argument of type 'Node' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Also, how can I deserialize to get the objects back?

Answer (score 1):

A class whose definition is recursive like your Node class can be serialized without any problems, as long as there are no circular references (infinite loops) in the data.

To use the ToBson extension method you need to add the following using statement:

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
```